# Windows 8 sends duplicate message to facebook user

Tags: windows-8, modern-ui, messaging

I'm facing issue with Windows 8 Metro messaging app. It send duplicate message to  user if he's accessing facebook with smartphone. Any message I send, appears twice, however user receives only single message. Any solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your messaging metro app is update to date. I would also check that all Windows updates are up to date, and installed.

Comment: I'm talking about Windows 8 Messaging app and not Facebook Metro app.